# Finding Service Version Number off of a Webpage Python2

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to find a way of acquiring a version number off of a web-page.

**In my python code:**

```
req = requests.get('http://mywebsite')
if req.status_code == 200:
    if versionNumber > 4.2:
        print "Version number is greater than 4.2!"
    elif versionNumber <= 4.2:
        print "Version number is equal or less than 4.2!"
else:
    pass
```

Now the real question is, how can I get the versionNumber from the site?
The version number can be seen on the request.

```
print req.content.find('Version ')
```

**Output:**

> Returns the index number where it starts, 49394.

**I have tried things like:**

```
start = req.content.find('Version ') # Returns 49394
end = start+12 # Version 4.10 is 12 characters long hence the start+12.
for i in range(start, end):
    sys.stdout.write(req.content[i]) # Returns Version 4.10
    i += 1
    if i == end:
        break
```

But that is not very good way. It wouldn't work if the language is changed, because the position is hardcoded.

Any suggestions on how could I acquire the version number from the site?

Answer (score 0):

## I found a way to do it! Here are the steps for other people:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

req = requests.get('http://mywebsite')
if req.status_code == 200:
    src = req.text # req.content works aswell
    txt = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    element = txt.find('h3', id=ID) # The first param is the element to look for, in my case h3. The second parameter is optional, it might be an id if you're looking for example divs.
    versionNumber = ''.join(map(str, str(element.contents).encode('UTF-8')))
    versionNumber = re.findall('\d+', versionNumber)
    while len(versionNumber) > 2:
        versionNumber.pop(0)
    versionNumber = versionNumber[0]+'.'+versionNumber[1]
    if float(versionNumber) > 4.2:
        print "Version number is greater than 4.2!"
    elif float(versionNumber) <= 4.2:
        print "Version number is equal or less than 4.2!"
else:
    pass
```